# AttributeError: 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'export'

Tags: python-3.x, android-studio, tensorflow

I have created a random forest classifier for a ML android app and I am using tensorflow for it, in the tutorial video, it shows the command model.export() to create a tensorflow lite file, however i am encountering the issue in the screenshot. any suggestions on how to do this?

```
model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(x_train,y_train)
model_pred = model.predict(x_test)

model.export(export_dir=r'C:\Users\laksh\Documents\lakshya computer backup\All in one farm',with_metadata = True)
```

```
AttributeError: 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'export'
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! Posting your code as a (link to the) image is a bad habit, consider editing your post and putting your code and errors as text instead of an image

Comment: thanks GooDeeJay, made the suggested changes. any ideas about the code? Thanks

Comment: can you please let us know which tutorial you're following?

Comment: I have tried to use the approach in the link below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_XOVkjXQbU

PS: I have never worked on ML projects before where I had to integrate python code in android app, so my approach might be wrong. Open to any suggestions to edi this or try a completely new approach.

Comment: Also in the video they have used an image_classifier but i need to use a random forest classifier, as I am training my data on seven attributes relating to crop yield. So any suggestions are helpful